# Issue with dropdown while implementing vertical tabs (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I try to implement vertical tab in dropdown menu of twitter bootstrap,
my code for "vertical tab" and "Drop down" work perfectly, but when I try to merge both, only tab headers are display. ([JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/57frK/))

Here is my code for "tab", "dropdown" and "tab with dropdown"

**Drop Down Code**

```
<div class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">dropdown</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropme1">
                        <li class="arrowdrop"><a href="#">Role Name, A-Z</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z2"><a href="#">Role Name, Z-A</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z3"><a href="#">Created on, Oldest first</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z4"><a href="#">Created on, Newest first</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z5"><a href="#">Last edited, Oldest first</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z6"><a href="#">Last edited, Newest first</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z7"><a href="#">Status, Ascending</a></li>
                        <li id = "a2z8"><a href="#">Status, Descending</a></li>
                       </ul>
```

**Vertical Tab Code**

```
<div class="tabbable verticaltabs-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ulfloatleft liremovefloat">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                <h3>Home</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                <h3>Profile</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
                <h3>Messages</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">
                <h3>Settings</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
                <h3>Contact</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Drop Down + Vertical Tab**

```
 <div class="tabbable verticaltabs-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ulfloatleft liremovefloat">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                <h3>Home</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
                <h3>Profile</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">
                <h3>Messages</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">
                <h3>Settings</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact">
                <h3>Contact</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


                <h3>Drop down with tab</h3>

                <div class="dropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">dropdown</a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                        <li class="arrowdrop"><a href="#">

                  <div class="tabbable verticaltabs-container">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ulfloatleft liremovefloat">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile1" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#messages1" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings1" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact1" data-toggle="tab">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home1">
                <h3>Home</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile1">
                <h3>Profile</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages1">
                <h3>Messages</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings1">
                <h3>Settings</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact1">
                <h3>Contact</h3>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


                        </a></li>

                       </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your tabs need to be wrapped in a `<form>` container inside a `<ul>` (instead of inside the anchor). This way you don't need the jquery event.stopPropagation() stuff.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
    <li class="arrowdrop"><a href="#">Tabs</a></li>
    <ul>
      <form>
      <div class="tabbable tabs-left">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>Section 1...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Section 2...</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### [**Demo**](http://bootply.com/60902)

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of things that need to be corrected in your code

the tab content inside dropdown is hidden behind tab headers, so you won't see it even if the tab worked.

You may add css like this to make it visible

```
.dropdown-menu .tab-content{
    padding-left:150px;
}
```

Also you need to trigger tabs additionally to make them work inside dropdown, by adding this:

```
$('.dropdown .nav a').click(function (e) {
      $(this).tab('show');
    });
```

Here I updated your jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/57frK/1/

Also you may want to correct styles for tab headers to show bottom borders

Comment: thanxs for your answer,
its good and working fine, really helpfull.